Raising both sides of $1\;\text{Newton}=10^5\;\text{Dynes}$ to power $1/5$ yields $1\;\text{Newton}=10\;\text{Dynes}$, which is false. What's wrong?
So, $1\;\text{Newton}= 10^5\;\text{Dynes}$. If I raise both sides to the power $\frac 1 5$ then it will become $1\;\text{Newton} = 10\;\text{Dynes}$, and hence the equation would be wrong.
Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong in this.

Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

Think of units as multipliers. $1n=10000d$ then if you raise both to the $1/5$ power, you get $1n^{1/5}=10d^{1/5}.$ That works over where a unit really is multiplicative, but not with temperature units Fahrenheit and Celsius.

$$1 \text{ Newton}^{\frac{1}{5}} = 10 \text{ Dynes}^{\frac{1}{5}}$$

Why the downvotes?

The units would also be affected by the exponentiation operations because for example you take a square of side $l = 10m$ to find its area we square $l$ and get
$l^{2}=100m^{2}$
see how the unit changed? its no more $m$.

can you explain using this equation?

@GamingGuru i wanted to write square, ended up writing a cube

@GamingGuru just edited it
